# Add custom columns from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, multiple-columns, rows

I want to write a query that pivots rows to columns with custom column names.

Here is my sample output:

```
Name Documents          Sent
---- ------------------ ----------
Paul Attachment1 - Paul 2020-01-01
Paul Attachment2 - Paul 2020-01-01
Ty   Attachment1 - Ty   2020-01-02
```

My desired output:

```
Name Attachment1        Attachment1Sent Attachment2        Attachment2Sent
---- ------------------ --------------- ------------------ ---------------
Paul Attachment1 - Paul 2020-01-01      Attachment2 - Paul 2020-01-01
Ty   Attachment1 - Ty   2020-01-02      NULL               NULL
```

**The maximum amount of documents is two, but the minimum is only one.**

I am using SQL Server. I believe I could either use `PIVOT` or `CROSS APPLY` to do this but I'm stuck on how to create custom column names. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We need to see what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name, 
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then document end) as document_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then sent end) as sent_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then document end) as document_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then sent end) as sent_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by sent) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```